# How to parallelize for-cycle using PLINQ?

Tags: c#, plinq

I have a task to parallelize iterations using PLINQ. For it I have a function based on for-cycle:

```
public void PointGenerator(int n, Random rnd)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        x = rnd.NextDouble(); 
        y = rnd.NextDouble(); // 
        if (((x - 0.5) * (x - 0.5) + (y - 0.5) * (y - 0.5)) < 0.25)
        {
            N_0++;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do it using PLINQ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try like this:

```
public bool Check(double x, double y)
{
    return ((x - 0.5) * (x - 0.5) + (y - 0.5) * (y - 0.5)) < 0.25;    
}

// ...

N_0 = Enumerable
    .Range(0, n)
    .Select(i => new { X = rnd.NextDouble(), Y = rnd.NextDouble() })
    .AsParallel()
    .Count(p => Check(p.X, p.Y));
```

As noted by [Roman Dvoskin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/782185/roman-dvoskin) in the comment under the other answer, [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects are not thread safe:

> However, Random objects are not thread safe. If your app calls Random methods from multiple threads, you must use a synchronization object to ensure that only one thread can access the random number generator at a time. If you don't ensure that the Random object is accessed in a thread-safe way, calls to methods that return random numbers return 0.

This problem can be worked around by generating all XY pairs first.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx) method on a [range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var randLock = new object();
Parallel.ForEach(
    Enumerable.Range(1, n)
,   () => { // if you needed the index, you could use i instead of ()
        lock (randLock) {
            x = rnd.NextDouble(); 
            y = rnd.NextDouble();
        }
        if (((x - 0.5) * (x - 0.5) + (y - 0.5) * (y - 0.5)) < 0.25) {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref N_0);
        }
    });
```

Note the use of [`Interlocked.Increment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `N_0++` to avoid concurrency issues. The use of `randLock` serves the same purpose: according to the documentation, [`System.Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) is not thread-safe.

Comment: Random is not thread safe according to MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Random(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What is the point of parallel when using a lock? Random is not parallelizable and there is no other work being done. @BartoszKP has the more correct answer. Although neither is fully correct because multiple threads are used with Random.

Comment: @RomanDvoskin The part outside `lock` is not free, but I agree, the `rnd.NextDouble()` call is probably going to dominate.

Comment: Only code that is not executed is free. The locks, threads have a bigger cost. The non functional, side effect-ful style has the biggest.